# List of List<>?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, list

I have defined a class called ScheduleSlot - I use a list of ScheduleSlots per row in my 'scheduler' application. But I must have several rows. Is it possible to have a list of `list<ScheduleSlot>?`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it has the type `List<List<ScheduleSlot>>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! So - what if I wanted to refer to one of the lists held in this list of lists?? For example, I may or may not want to reference a list called 'day1', i.e. day1 may or may not exist depending on user settings.

Comment: You can always initialize them as empty.  Otherwise, create a class wrapper with accessor functions that handle this.

Comment: That's confused me completely sorry, still rather new to this. To simplify my question - how can I access a list in this list of lists assuming I know it definitely exists? So I've added the list as described in this thread, now how do I refer to it?

Comment: @DanielMcNulty: You can access via index: `listOfLists[0]` gets the first list for example. `listOfLists[2][1]` would be the second item in the third list.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, appreciated. I think I'm going to opt for a dictionary now though.

Comment: @DanielMcNulty: If it fits your needs, sure.

Answer (score 5):

```
var a = new List<List<ScheduleSlot>> ();
```

Remember that the first list is empty. To add:

```
a.Add (new List<ScheduleSlot> ());
```

Then

```
a[0].Add (new ScheduleSlot());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Adding a list seems fairly simple - but how do I retrieve a list from this list of lists??

Comment: a[0][0] or foreach (var outerList in a) foreach (var innerList in outerList)

Comment: Supposing I name the lists tho. So I have:

List<ScheduleSlot> newList = new List<ScheduleSlot>();
ListOfLists.Add(newList);

Can I refer to 'newList' in my code??

Comment: @DanielMcNulty, if you want to give the lists names you would be better using a dictionary.

Comment: Yer I see what you mean, brilliant, thanks a lot for all the responses here!

Comment: This dictionary suggestion has just solved so many of my problems!! Including other ones I have in other solutions too! Thanks again mate

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.

```
List<List<ScheduleSlots>> nList = new List<List<ScheduleSlots>>();
```